# Is there a performance/usability benefit to using useCallback for InputElement Events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When not passing a callback to a child and just using it on the present component, Is there a benefit to wraping the callback in a `useCallback`?
This:

```
 const Foo = (
  const [count, setCount] = useState(500);

  const onChange = useCallback((e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setCount(Number(e.target.value));
  }, [setCount]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        Delay: <input value={count} onChange={onChange} type="number" />
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Verse This:

```
 const Foo = (
  const [count, setCount] = useState(500);

  const onChange =(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setCount(Number(e.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        Delay: <input value={count} onChange={onChange} type="number" />
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-stonebraker-48xhs?file=/src/Counter.tsx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see no benefit there when used internally since each state update (`setCount(Number(e.target.value));`) necessarily rerenders the component anyway and all the callback is doing is enqueueing a state update.

There may be a small (*very negligible*) improvement in memory usage if using a single declared, memoized function for the life of the component.

If the callback was used in an `useEffect` hook it could be provided as a stable reference and be removed from dependency arrays, but typically here you'd just move the function into the effect callback. This doesn't fit the use case you are asking about, but it's a valid use case that isn't passing callbacks down to children.

Comment: Even if it was doing heavy work there is no benefit of using `useCallback` because each rendering redeclare the function, it does not call it. if you want to store data coming from an heavy computation you should use `useMemo`.  One small benefit  on using `useCallback` is that the callback itself is `memoized` and  subsequently render will not cause additional binding to the same variable declaration.

Comment: @AntonioPantano Ah, you know, you're correct. Still no benefit in that case. Thanks, I'll update.